# What does "Marked for death" do?

Tags: for-honor

One of Valkyries abilities is Scout which makes all enemies "Marked for Death" but what does that actually do and does it affect all enemies or just ones close to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [gamespressure](https://guides.gamepressure.com/forhonor/guide.asp?ID=38604), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CompetitiveForHonor/comments/72dn49/does_valkyries_scout_feat_apply_after_death/) and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/forhonor/comments/9gxjf8/marked_for_death/) the targeted enemy team shows up on the radar, get's highlighted in white for your allies and receives some attack and defense debuffs.

Comment: But I'm wondering what those attack/defense debuffs are. Is it small just like 5% or bigger like 30%

Comment: The only answer I found is on [steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/304390/discussions/0/1696043806552282352/, says -20% defence. I can only guess it is in the same percentage for the attack too.